# When I defined a function I got: error unexpected token: (

Tags: crystal-lang

I have already seen the community of Crystal, but I couldn't find this problem.

```
def Twosum(a = [] of Int32, target = 0)

    map = {} of Int32 : Int32

    a.each_index do |i|

        diff = target - a[i]

        if map.key?(diff):

            return [map.fetch(diff), i]

        elsif

            map[a[i]] = i

        end
    end

    return 0`enter code here`

end

a = [1,4,6,3]
target = 7
puts(Twosum(a,target))
```

What's the problem?

Comment: what line does it say the failure is on?

Comment: line 1 def Twosum()

Answer (score 2):

Many problems. The one you ask about is: Crystal is very opinionated regarding case. Methods must start with lowercase; yours starts with uppercase, which Crystal does not like at all. Some other problems:

- `{} of Int32 : Int32` should use a fat arrow, not a colon: `{} of Int32 => Int32`
- `if` statement does not end with a colon, it is not Python.
- There is no method named `key?`; use `has_key?`
- `fetch` (in current Crystal version) requires either a block or a second argument that specifies a default; if you do not need to specify a default behaviour (and you don't, since you check whether the key exists), you can just use `[]`.

I'm really not sure what the code is intended to do, so I can't comment on the logic, semantics and style; but here's your code without syntax errors:

```
def twosum(a = [] of Int32, target = 0)
    map = {} of Int32 => Int32
    a.each_index do |i|
        diff = target - a[i]
        if map.has_key?(diff)
            return [map[diff], i]
        elsif
            map[a[i]] = i
        end
    end
    return 0
end

a = [1, 4, 6, 3]
target = 7
puts(twosum(a, target))
```

Comment: thank you for explaining everything for me, this code is for the leetcode  since the web page of leetcode doesn't support crystal, so i write it by myself, i don't know much about crystal therefore i want to practice it by this way. thank you very much. you're very kind!

Comment: could you please tell me more ways to loop a list by crystal since i use python much more however it's slow in some situation.

Comment: Well, you could have used `each_with_index` here instead of `each_index`; and obviously there's `each`. Other than that, there's many different specialised functions, you'd have to be more specific as I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: yes,i am asking about this. and i have another question. i want to defined a ListNode class. i don't if this is correct.

Comment: `code`
class ListNode
     def initialize(x : Int32)
           @val = x
           @next = Nil
     end
end
`code`

Comment: Please don't write code in comments, that's not what they're for. Also, if you have new questions that are not clarifications of the current question, you should make a new question (and link to a previous question if its context is needed). Thirdly... try to run it and see if it works. If you tried that, you'd see it's not correct - `@next` doesn't know its type.

Comment: i get it, i have already tried it. it's said undefined method next. but angway thank you again